# Heat semigroup estimate on complete Riemannian manifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, fa.functional-analysis

Consider a complete noncompact Riemannian manifold $M$ such that the heat kernel $h_t(x, y)$ satisfies
$h_t(x, y) \leq Ct^{-n/2}$. Consider a function $u \in L^p(M)$. How can we prove that $e^{t\Delta}u(x) \leq \frac{C^{1/p}}{t^{n/2p}}||u||_{L^p}$? Thanks!

Comment: I suspect you need some spatial decay conditions on $h_t$ also. Using only your stated assumptions and the functional relationship between the heat kernel and the semigroup flow (and absolutely nothing else), it does not appear possible.